# Как растянуть div со всем содержимым на всю ширину окна

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, html5

Появилась потребность растянуть блок на всю ширину экрана. Структура блока:

```css
.wrap{
    display: inline-block;
}
.wrap span{
    padding: 1vw;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2.5vw;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
    <span>hello world!</span>
</div>
```

При этом изменять размер шрифта или какие либо свойства дочерних элементов `div.wrap` нежелательно, либо делать это как-то пропорционально. Ниже нарисовал схему как есть сейчас и как должно получится в итоге.

[image: Схема результата]
[image: Начальная схема]

Если с картинками все понятно, как и какими методами их растягивать, то вот с блоками я информации не нахожу. Буду благодарен за вашу помощь в этом вопросе.

Comment: прочитать что такое display:block/inline-block и span.

Comment: @Slam расскажите, в чём конкретно сложность? Хотите, чтобы  размер шрифта увеличивался пропорционально размеру div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужен резиновый текст, который будет пропорционально ужиматься и растягиваться, то лучше использовать svg:

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 20" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="background-color: #b9b9b9">
    <text x="50%" y="50%" fill="black" font-family="sans-serif" font-size=".7em" dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle">Hello, World!</text>
</svg>
```